# How to integrate Asio network library with Qt library?

Tags: qt, exec

I want to use Asio and Qt together ? each of them have a two method that must be called and each of them are blocking for example : Asio has io_service.run() and qt has QCoreApplication.exec() if I run one of them then another cannot be run.

I have two solutions:

1. create another thread and call io_service.run() from that.
2. create a timer with 100ms cycle and call io_service.poll() from same thread that call QCoreApplication.exec().

These solutions are correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate Boost.Asio main loop in GUI framework like Qt4 or GTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk)

Answer (score 2):

This is simple solution and works on every platform, but it has some minor drawback. You are introducing latency to asio-part of your application, which may be acceptable or not - depends on your case.

You may be interested in [my solution](https://github.com/peper0/qtasio), that makes real integration of asio and QT mainloops.

Look also at the following question for more on this topic: [How to integrate Boost.Asio main loop in GUI framework like Qt4 or GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk/)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to look into multi-threading your application. Qt helps you out with pretty good [platform-independent threading classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html). You'll also need to address [communication](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/6276) between [objects owned by different threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop) and also will need to bear in mind that [painting is limited outside of the GUI thread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/threads-modules.html#painting-in-threads).

Comment: No, In this way, Qt use select architecture and I need proactor architecture in Linux kernel 2.6 that Asio has this feature. So this not my question? **I need to use Asio.** sorry for late answer.

Comment: I understood your question to mean that: You need to use ASIO in your Qt app but were not sure whether/how to multithread it. Apologies for the confusion, but what is your exact question? :)

Comment: are my former solutions good? in performance: calling io_service.poll() every 100 ms is a good work?