# How to do epoll equivalent in boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a long lived process that will get through asio from a variety of sources such as a websocket connection. If these sources were going to just send data once then my process could just call async_read the correct number of times then call ios.run() to wait for all those reads to finish. However, my process is long lived

Comment: You can *still* use `async_read`. Since they are *asynchronous* you can have many pending such operations, and the ASIO event loop will do the polling and execution as needed. If you're worried about the ASIO event loop blocking your main thread, then put it in its own thread?

Comment: Yes I know I can use async_read but eventually ios.run() will return and the program will exit. How do I get the ios to wait forever for new input?

Comment: Call `ios.run()` in a loop, while the service is not stopped.

Comment: That is basically a while loop polling. The whole point of epoll is to avoid burning cpu cycles in a loop.

Comment: @user782220 see io_service::work (I'll find a suitable duplicate). This is indeed the whole point of async io and Asio.

Comment: Integrating Asio with an existing event loop: [`run()` vs. `poll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705411/boostasio-io-service-run-vs-poll-or-how-do-i-integrate-boostasio-in-ma) and e.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk)